# Basic Vim - Search and Replace text bounded by specific characters

Tags: regex, vim, replace

Say I wanted to replace :

```
"Christoph Waltz" = "That's a Bingo";
"Gary Coleman" = "What are you talking about, dear Willis?";
```

to just have :

```
"Christoph Waltz"
"Gary Coleman"
```

i.e. I want to remove all the characters including and after the `=` and the `;`

I thought the regex for finding the pattern would be `\=.*?\;`. In vim, I tried :

```
:%s/\=.*?\;$//g
```

but it gave me an `Invalid Command` error and `Nothing after \=`. How do I remove the above text? Apologies, but I'm new to this.

Comment: Do you need to keep the last semicolon? Because if you don't, you can just simplify the regex to:

:%s/=.*//g

And that would do the trick (note that the equality sign doesn't have to be escaped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim's regular expression dialect is different; its escaping is optimized for text searches. See `:help perl-patterns` for a comparison with Perl regular expressions. As @EvergreenTree has noted, you can influence the escaping behavior with special atoms; cp. `:help /\v`.

For your example, the non-greedy match is `.\{-}`, not `.*?`, and, as mentioned, you mustn't escape several literal characters:

```
:%s/ =.\{-};$//
```

(The `/g` flag is superfluous, too; there can be only one match anchored to the end via `$`.)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of vim's weird handling of regexes by default.  Instead of `\=` interpreting as a literal `=`, it interprets it as a special regex character.  To make vim's regex system work more normally, you can prefix it with `\v`, which is *"very magic"* mode.  This should do the trick:

```
%s/\v\=.*\;$//g
```

I won't explain how vim enterprets every single character in very magic mode here, but you can read about it in this help topic:

```
:help /magic
```